Laravel Mysql specific table "SELECT" infinity loading
I cannot select from a specific table in MySQL with help Laravel. Infinite loading, no exceptions.
I tried with other tables, and they are selected perfectly. I checked usability with
SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE in_use>0 AND `Table`='item';

and there is no locked information.

Solved.
However. I'm trying to run outside of docker. And it is started working
